# Create Wifi Access Across Street

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a park across the street (a busy street). And I would love to have wifi available there. It's roughly in the 50-100 yard range. I'm curious what's possible for me to extend my wifi to a specific general area. I can't hook up anything at the park to receive the signal. I would only have my laptop with me.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I've seen answers to this in other forums, but they are all quite dated. I'm wondering what is the best method in 2017.

Comment: 802.11ac range would barely be there and that's if you lived in a plastic house.  What you want is unrealistic.

Answer (score 2):

If you have line of sight, you can build a cantenna for your place.  Aim at park.  Go to park. Enjoy wi-fi.  I've sent wireless 300+ yards using a cantenna at one end and just a laptop at the other, using old Cisco Aironet cards.